# How do I use map[string]struct{}

Tags: go, docker

So I am busy using http://godoc.org/github.com/samalba/dockerclient

Using CreateContainer (http://godoc.org/github.com/samalba/dockerclient#DockerClient.CreateContainer)

To setup a new container

```
containerConfig := &dockerclient.ContainerConfig{
    Image:        imageName,
    AttachStdin:  true,
    AttachStdout: true,
    AttachStderr: true}

containerID, err = docker.CreateContainer(containerConfig, containerName)
```

works correctly and I get a container, however, there is no exposed ports. Looking at the docker API(https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.15/), I need to set

"ExposedPorts - An object mapping ports to an empty object in the form of: "ExposedPorts": { "/: {}" }"

Looking at the godoc for the Go dockclient lib I am using, I see you can pass it as

```
ExposedPorts    map[string]struct{}
```

But I have no idea on what to do here, from the docker api example passing :

```
 "ExposedPorts":{
             "22/tcp": {}
     }
```

is enough, so how do I do the struct bit in the my containerConfig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your containerConfig

```
ExposedPorts: map[string]struct{}{
    "22/tcp": {},
}
```

Eg

```
containerConfig := &dockerclient.ContainerConfig{
    Image:        imageName,
    AttachStdin:  true,
    AttachStdout: true,
    AttachStderr: true,
    ExposedPorts: map[string]struct{}{
        "22/tcp": {},
    },
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/dJSd2E4ZKh)

Comment: Why is the struct every necessary here? Why not just have a list of strings?

Comment: @dalanmiller A list of strings is essentially what it is, but the API specifies a `map[string]struct{}` which is more like a set of strings - one which you can look up a string quickly, but they are kept in no particular order.